# Bootstrapping 95% CI for probability estimate returning narrow range

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, central-limit-theorem

I have a probability estimate for an intractable underlying distribution. For a contemporary example, let's say it is the probability of a team $T$ making it to the postseason in American football.

This probability has been estimated by running $n$ simulations and finding the proportions of the logistic output, where 1 is qualifying for the postseason and 0 is failing to qualify.

Let's say I then resample from the $n$ chains and calculate the proportion in each resampling. Over 50 resamples the proportions are:

```
R <- c(0.8807, 0.8817, 0.8848, 0.8809, 0.8848, 0.8842, 0.8844, 0.8848, 0.8861, 0.8836, 0.8886, 0.8898, 0.8899, 0.8825, 0.8866, 0.8791, 0.8803, 0.8801, 0.8863, 0.8829, 0.8866, 0.8836, 0.8840, 0.8870, 0.8860, 0.8829, 0.8836, 0.8871, 0.8756, 0.8837, 0.8824, 0.8822, 0.8888, 0.8814, 0.8825, 0.8817, 0.8848, 0.8747, 0.8859, 0.8884, 0.8887, 0.8847, 0.8869, 0.8821, 0.8887, 0.8846, 0.8804, 0.8825, 0.8805, 0.8871)
```

Via Central Limit Theorem, I can calculate the sample mean and standard deviation as:

```
mean_r <- mean(R)
s_r <- sd(R) / sqrt(50)
```

and the 95% confidence intervals as

```
lower <- qnorm(0.025, mean = mean_r, sd = s_r)
upper <- qnorm(0.975, mean = mean_r, sd = s_r)
```

this can also be plotted as:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(R), aes(x = R)) + geom_histogram() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = qnorm(0.025, mean = mean_r, sd = s_r), linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = qnorm(0.975, mean = mean_r, sd = s_r), linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = mean_r, colour = "red") +
    labs(title = "mean in red, 95% CI dashed", x = "x")
```

In my actual use case I've done $n = 10000$ resamples just to show a more canonical 'bell-shaped' PDF but that shouldn't hugely twist the results.

[image]
where clearly the 95% confidence intervals are extremely close to the mean. This can be confirmed by printing the results:

```
print(paste("the mean of the resamples is", mean_r))
print(paste("the lower bound of the estimated 95% CI is", lower))
print(paste("the upper bound of the estimated 95% CI is", upper))
```

I also tried using the `boot` package:

```
B <- boot(R,function(u,i) mean(u[i]),R=1000)
boot.ci(B,type=c("basic","perc"))
```

which gives the same results. Am I misunderstanding something about the 95% CI in this circumstance, or am I doing something wrong in my calculation?

Comment: What do you mean by  "the 95% confidence intervals are extremely close to the mean". Perhaps I misunderstood your question but I dont' see this information in the post.

Comment: the range of the CI is extremely small- see the dashed lines in the plot- compared to the distribution of samples. Though it's entirely possible maybe I have misunderstood calculating the confidence interval in this context

Comment: I can't identify what your samples might be.  If they are the elements of `R`, they appear awfully tightly scattered to me -- but their values aren't anything like those portrayed in your graphs.  You aren't calculating the sample standard deviation: you compute the *standard error of the mean* in `s_r`.  Maybe this is the source of your problem?

Comment: ahh, my mistake. Yes the elements of R. I copied the wrong graph but the idea is the same.

I'm not sure about that interpretation, see https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_probability/BS704_Probability12.html for the sample standard deviation, but also, it wouldn't explain the values return from the {boot} functionality?

Comment: It looks like what you are doing with the confidence intervals is correct for that step.  I'm wondering though if the problem with the results not matching your intuition is that you are using the proportions from the simulations as your observations.  Perhaps you want to use one simulation, and use the 1's and 0's as the observations ?